# Jquery Select2 tagging input?

Tags: jquery-select2, select2-rails

I am using `Select2` in a `Rails` application. I would like to know if it is possible to restrict the input a user can pass into the tagging control using regex. So basically I want a user to only be able to type `a-z, 0-9 or + and #`. The rest of the characters should not be possible to enter into the control.

How do I achieve this?Thanks

Comment: can you post fiddle of your workarounds?